# Cannot access key in resource file from mvc 4 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, resources

I have a resource file called Constants.resx which contains some strings. From the controller I am trying to access to a new string that I have just added to Constants.resx file but it is not recognized by the compiler (intellisense is not showning me the new string just added) and of course when I type it, an error is shown.

In the controller header I have added below line:

```
using Resources;
```

and to access to the new string just added I do the following:

```
Resources.Constants.NewString
```

I access to other strings in Constants.resx file using the same approach and no problem, they are recognized correctly, but not this new one.

Any ideas?

UPDATED:
My resource file for my mvc 4 app was added by selecting "Add > new item" from App_GlobalResources context menu and finally selecting "Resource file".

My resource files properties are:

```
Build action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy
Custom Tool: GlobalResourceProxyGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace: (left blank)
```

Also I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express edition.

I can see the compiler is throwing a warning saying it cannot find the custom Tool 'GlobalResourceProxyGenerator' in the system.

Comment: if you are seeing the other strings in that resource trying cleaning and rebuilding your project

Comment: @MattBodily it does not work for me. I had to add manually to Constants.resx.cs. Then it works. It seems like each time I add a new string to the resource file, its Constants.resx.cs is not being regenerated. Why?

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio 2010 express does not support GlobalResourceProxyGenerator and must be changed into ResXFileCodeGenerator (if you want internal references) or PublicResXFileCodeGenerator  (if you want public references). And then access key strings using App_GlobalResources.Constants.MyKey or only Constants.MyKey if you put using MyProject.App_GlobalResources. See below link: http://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&t=6062~-1

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the namespace of all the resource files as a common namespace like ViewResource. Then change the access modifier in the resource file as public. Now you can access those resource files.

Build action: Content

Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

Custom Tool: GlobalResourceProxyGenerator

Custom Tool Namespace: **ViewResource**

Access Modifier : **Public** (In all resource Files)